# Prestashop I can't upload product images from backend

Tags: prestashop

I can't upload product images from backend, always the last image is incomplete and doesn't upload, no matter if is a single image o are multiples images, the progress bar is freeze.

I deleted the cache, I activated the debug mode, I checked the php_error.log and prod.log, dev.log in the prestashop installation and I can't see any error there. Well, I only can to see an Ajax error in debug mode and browser console, a POST petition without status response (see attachments). How I Can debug this?

The images are very small < 500kb.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

What setting or log I must to check?

My current settings are:

- **OS**: Ubuntu 18.04.2
- **Prestashop**: 1.7.5.2
- **Folders Permissions**: 755
- **Files Permissions**: 644
- **PHP**: 7.1

  - memory_limit = 1024M
  - max_execution_time = 300
  - max_input_time = 300
  - upload_max_filesize = 20M
  - post_max_size = 20M
  - max_input_vars = 10000
  - safe_mode = off
- **Browsers**: Chrome, Firefox, Opera.

Comment: Check if you have write permissions for your image directories and try to regenerate all images

Comment: Hi @AlexanderGrosul. I have 755 for directories and 644 for files. The stranger thing it's that I can upload files from eMagicOne client, but I can't upload through backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the modules installed that could affect the product backend area and I found [[Free Module] Image Optimization Via Resmush.it Service](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/446476-free-module-image-optimization-via-resmushit-service/).

When I deactivated this module the product images uploads works fine. Now, I must check what is the cause of the issue into this module.

Answer (score 1):

Que hay acerca de esto:

[image: Compilacion de plantillas]

Que navegador usas? ya intentaste con otro navegador?

Comment: I use Chrome, Firefox and Opera. The cache is inactive. I cleaned the cache when I used it.